# rails: associated record is deleted also when deleting a record, can't see why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the problem that inside my e-commerce rails 3.0.x application I have products, line_items and carts.

a line_item belongs to a cart and a product.
a product can have many line_items.
if I delete a product, the line_items should be deleted as well (:dependent => :destroy)

Now, the strange thing is, when I delete a line_item from the cart this will delete my complete product record as well!

Here is the necessary code:

```
#cart_view.erb
<% for line_item in cart.line_items %>

<!-- HTML omitted -->

<!-- This link actually removes not only the line_item from cart, but also deletes the product...? . -->
<%= link_to "remove", line_item, :confirm => 'Remove from cart?', :method => :delete %>

<% end %>

#product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   # for cart
   has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
   has_many :stock_items, :dependent => :destroy
end

#line_item.rb
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product

end

# stock_item.rb
class StockItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :line_items

end


#line_items_controller.rb

class LineItemsController < ApplicationController


   def destroy
     @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
     @cart = @line_item.cart
     @line_item.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Removed from cart."
     redirect_to @cart
   end
end
```

This behaviour was not always like this, at least I don't remember. Also I see nothing wrong here at first glance, so any ideas are highly appreciated.

**edit**

db table definitions (i use mysql2 db adapter):

```
| line_items | CREATE TABLE `line_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unit_price` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cart_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_item_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `line_items_cart_id_fk` (`cart_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `line_items_cart_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `carts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| products | CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subtitle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'GBP',
  `legacy` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `product_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

** edit 2 **

the `rails s` log when I hit the rmove line_item link:

```
Started POST "/line_items/16?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-27 16:51:06 +0100
  SQL (1.6ms)  describe `roles_users`
  Processing by LineItemsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"sN78OIdiVW5WgSoLA3JR7RFOWIy5B+j1XLqe47vZf3I=", "locale"=>"en", "id"=>"16"}
  LineItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`id` = 16 LIMIT 1
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 16 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`id` = 16
  StockItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
  AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `stock_items` WHERE `stock_items`.`id` = 7
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
  Product::Translation Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `product_translations`.* FROM `product_translations` WHERE (`product_translations`.product_id = 7)
  AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `product_translations` WHERE `product_translations`.`id` = 11
  AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `product_translations` WHERE `product_translations`.`id` = 12
  ProductLike Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `product_likes`.* FROM `product_likes` WHERE (`product_likes`.product_id = 7)
  Asset Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `assets`.* FROM `assets` WHERE (`assets`.product_id = 7)
  AREL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `assets` WHERE `assets`.`id` = 6
  SetItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `set_items`.* FROM `set_items` WHERE (`set_items`.product_id = 7)
  StockItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `stock_items`.* FROM `stock_items` WHERE (`stock_items`.product_id = 7)
  AREL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 7
  SQL (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/carts/16?locale=en
Completed 302 Found in 3093ms
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/activesupport-3.0.17/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb:23: warning: regexp match /.../n against to UTF-8 string
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong from above, are their any clues from the db layer (i.e. foreign key constraints?)..

Comment: Don't know if it has anything to do with it, but `:method` in the link is `:delete` and the method you refer to in the controller is `destroy` (I haven't learned Rails 3.x yet, that is perhaps normal).

Comment: ok, worth a try, I'm awaiting the explanation of this with interest (will soon be upgrading from 1.x to 3.x in a big system so always good to learn about strange things happening, and please don't comment the "1.x" - I know...)

Comment: added db definitions, will look for relevant logs now

Comment: And what happens with the `cart`?

Comment: logs added. 244an what do you mean? nothing has to happen with the cart at this point. could be that i delete one product of many in the cart, so I just want to redirect to it after deleting the line_item. if i deleted the last product, i show an empty cart.

Comment: Are there any other relations and dependencies between `line_items`, `stock_items`, and `products` ?

Comment: hi dimuch, i think you are on the right track, I added the other dependencies and it looks like there inside stock_items is a wrong :dependent => :delete. add yours again as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I mean, something is happening that is not supposed to happen, and regarding to the code you are showing (you are not showing all other relations as an example) it shouldn't happen. So all clues are of interest, thats why I asked about the `cart`, but that remains then...

Comment: Looks like you have incorrect `destroy` or `delete` dependency in `LineItem` -> `StockItem` -> `Product` chain.